# PHRoute redirecting my resources

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem building a little mvc framework from scratch. I am using PHP and I have pulled the PHRoute package. The problem is that it tries to dispatch the requests to files, as application requests (instead of delivering the file, it tries to find a route). This leads to 500 error (route for css or js files not exists). I have tried to absolute define the path e.g.

```
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
```

However I am still getting the same result.

My .htaccess is the following (and is located in the web root)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

My folder structure is

```
--root

   --public

     --css

     --js

     --index.php (router)

     --.htaccess
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It has do be an Apache issue. Otherwise the request wouldn't be handed to index.php at all. Check if css/styles.css exists on the server. Check if css and css/styles.css have correct access rights (eg. are owned by the apache user / group, most often called apache or www-data. index.php should have the same access rights)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. I just added the "BASE_URL" before the CSS file.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url ?>css/styles.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your .htaccess file has the directive "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f".
2. Check if the result absolute path to /css/styles.css is correct.

When you .htaccess file has that directive, if the result absolute path is correct, the router should not be called.